# How to count the numbers of columns while iterating over results using Oracle OCCI library?

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

Help me, I want to make a generic function that get the results of any query string and puts all rows into another variable. When iterating over a row, how can I know the numbers of columns available?

```
Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment();
Connection *conn = env->createConnection("user","pass");
quantLinhas = 0;
if( conn != NULL ) {
    Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement(query);
    ResultSet *rs = stmt->executeQuery();
    resultadoSQL->linhas.clear();
    while (rs->next()) {
        aux.campos.clear();
        numbers_colums = rs->whatever_method() //WHAT DO I DO HERE??
        for(i = 0; i < numbers_colums ; i++) {  
            aux.campos.push_back( rs->getString(i) );
            quantLinhas++;
        }
        resultadoSQL->linhas.push_back( aux );
    }
    stmt->closeResultSet(rs);
    conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
    env->terminateConnection(conn);
}
```

Comment: Does your connector have functions for retrieving the number of fields or columns?

Comment: I'm using OCCI as the connector

Answer (score 1):

According the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10764/reference027.htm#i1082585) you can use `getColumnListMetaData` function. The number of elements in the returned vector might be what you want. You may check if each element is of [PTYPE_COL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10764/reference020.htm#LNCPP1014) to ensure it.

Comment: but `getColumnListMetaData` returns a `vector<MetaData>`. I need to retrieve a `vector<string>`

Comment: Why is that? You want the number of columns, which is somehow in that vector: Either each element represents one column or each element with PTYPE_COL is one column. So either count them yourself or just get the number of elements, your choice.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  vector<MetaData> columnList = rs->getColumnListMetaData();
  numbers_colums = columnList.size();
  columnList.clear();
```

it worked for me.
[source link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10778/metadata.htm)